# Disable incoming gmail/Talk calls

Tags: calls, google-talk

I occasionally use the gmail on my computer browser to voice chat with friends, however when they call me though their gmail my device picks up the call rather then my computer. more precisely ever since I got my device and synced it to google, the **"Talk" application** intercepts the call, rings in, and asks to answer/reject.

how can I disable this feature so that the gmail on my computer would catch this call as it used to?